# Here shows up the body but not subject. Cannot figure out what is wrong in this

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
<a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=abc@gmail.com&body=SomeBody&Subject=freechocolate" target="_blank">reply</a>
```

In this code, it opens a new Gmail tab and has auto-filled to and body but the subject does not seems to be working. Can anyone tell what's the solution to this problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

Not having worked with Gmail like that, a possible solution is that in the GET request the subject is the only capitalised variable, should it be a lower case like the other variable names?

Comment: I have tried that too subject in lower case but it's not working